# How do I use Multipart::from_request with a tiny_http::Request?

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to use the `tiny_http` integration in the `multipart` crate:

```
extern crate multipart;
extern crate tiny_http;

use multipart::server::tiny_http as tiny_http_trait;
use multipart::server::Multipart;
use tiny_http::*;

fn main() {
    let server = Server::http("0.0.0.0:8080").unwrap();
    loop {
        match server.recv() {
            Ok(request) => {
                let mult = Multipart::from_request(request).unwrap();
            }
            Err(s) => eprintln!("{:#?}", s),
        };
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error when trying to extract multipart form data from the request:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `tiny_http::Request: multipart::server::HttpRequest` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:13:28
   |
13 |                 let mult = Multipart::from_request(request).unwrap();
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `multipart::server::HttpRequest` is not implemented for `tiny_http::Request`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <&'r mut tiny_http::Request as multipart::server::HttpRequest>
   = note: required by `multipart::server::Multipart::<()>::from_request`
```

That trait implementation does exist, and I'm able to use it directly with `HttpRequest` functions:

```
let boundary = <&mut Request as HttpRequest>::multipart_boundary(&&mut request);
```

I cannot seem to use that same syntax to use `tiny_http::Request` as a `multipart::server::HttpRequest` in `multipart::server::Multipart::from_request(...)`

Here is my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "db_interface"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = [""]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
tiny_http = "0.6.2"

[dependencies.multipart]
version = "0.16.1"
features = ["tiny_http"]
```

Comment: Try using `Multipart::from_request(<&mut request as HttpRequest>)`. And please don't layer references.

Comment: @Locke that one results in a syntax error: `error: expected '::', found ')'`

Comment: Also, I didn't have an option but to layer the references, and it's why I considered that solution sub-optimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the compiler tells you, you need a mutable reference:

```
<&'r mut tiny_http::Request as multipart::server::HttpRequest>
```

Declare the request as mutable and then take a reference to it:

```
match server.recv() {
    Ok(mut request) => {
        let mult = Multipart::from_request(&mut request).unwrap();
    }
    Err(s) => eprintln!("{:#?}", s),
};
```